# convert an array into individual strings

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have the following arrays and I would like to convert each one of them into individual strings. In other words, break the array into individual pieces.

```
  $formatsArray = $_POST['formats'];
      $topicsArray = $_POST['topics'];
```

This is because I would like to include the individual strings in the following query "

```
  $resources = "select * from resources where
                    stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'
                    AND format LIKE '%".$formats."%'";


      $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $resources);
```

This is because format expect an individual string for comparison, such as lets assume the array is `["video", "blogs", "articles"]`, it wouldn't work if format was to be compared with `video,blogs,articles` but rather video, blogs or articles.

I hope this is clear, and for any clarification, please advise.

All the best,

Update:

```
$formats = explode(',', $formatsArray);
      $topics = explode(',', $topicsArray);


      $resources = "select * from resources where
                    stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'
                    AND format LIKE '%".$formats."%' AND topic LIKE '%".$topics."%' ";
```

update:

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $resources);


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {

    $data[] = array(
      'format' => $row['format'],
      'title' => $row['title'],
      'costs' => $row['cost'],
      'stage' => $row['stage'],
      'topic' => $row['topic'],
      'link' => $row['link']
    );
  }
```

**Update**

```
  include('db.php');


  $query = 'select * from resources where ';
  $query .= 'stage LIKE :stage and';
  $execute[':stage'] = '%' . $stage . '%';
  if(!empty($_POST['formats'])){
  foreach($_POST['formats'] as $key => $format) {
      $query .= 'format LIKE :format' . $key . ' and ';
      $execute[':format' . $key] = '%' . trim($format) . '%';
  }
  }
  if(!empty($_POST['topics'])){
  foreach($_POST['topics'] as $key => $topic) {
      $query .= 'topic LIKE :topic' . $key . ' and ';
      $execute[':topic' . $key] = '%' . trim($topic)  . '%';
  }
  }
  $query = rtrim($query, ' and ');
  if(!empty($execute)) {
      $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute($execute);
  } else {
      echo 'You must search for something';
  }


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $data[] = array(
          'format' => $row['format'],
          'title' => $row['title'],
          'costs' => $row['cost'],
          'stage' => $row['stage'],
          'topic' => $row['topic'],
          'link' => $row['link']
        );
      }
```

Comment: So a comma is the separator? Use explode then iterate through the array and build your query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for the response. the comma is not a seperator. in the db, you have for instance "video"   or "blogs" or "articles" for example, so if the array is implode with a comma such as video,blogs,articles it wouldn't match any entry. could you elaborate a bit more on your solution

Comment: Not implode, explode. So you have `$_POST['formats']` which is `video,blogs,articles` right? So if you explode on `,` then iterate through that array you will have each term separately..

Comment: thanks i have added an update at the bottom of my initial post. how would i proceed with the next step

Comment: `$formats` and `$topics` always have the same number of elements?

Comment: not always the number of elements is undertermined as it is based on user selection

Comment: How is the table structured? Would there only be one value in the `format` column, one value in the `topics` column for each entry?

Comment: [`if ($_POST['topics'] == "'; DROP TABLE resources; --") { echo 'I got pwned :('; }`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2891365)

Comment: yes format and topics column expect one entry each, such as format would only accept video or blogs for instance or topics idea generation, only one

Comment: @user193130 i am not familiar with prepared statement but will address it once we figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the necessity of prepared statements, you could do:

```
  $formats = implode('","', $formatsArray);
  $topics = implode('","', $topicsArray);

  $resources = "select * from resources where
                stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'
                AND format IN(".$formats.") AND topic IN(\"".$topics."\") ";
```

By adding the `"` before and after each `,` when you `implode` each array, your array would become e.g.

```
video","blogs","articles
```

So, we need to add the `"` to the beginning and end of each `IN` list. This will make the final query like:

```
select * from resources where
stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'
AND format IN("video","blogs","articles") AND ...
```

Comment: `$formatsArray` isn't a PHP array in the OPs post. Explode first and then implode with quotes. Also, in the query you've escaped the quotes around `$topics` but not around `$formats`. This might be confusing.

Comment: Thank you, @onik -- I guess the variable name threw me off. :P And the missing escaped quotes was totally my bad, thanks for catching.

Comment: thanks. i unfortunatetly get the following error: trim() expects parameter to be string, array given

Comment: @user3907211 Sorry about that -- I thought your `$formatsArray` *was* a string. Answer is edited and should work now -- although it looks like @chris85's answer did the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do it. This also will resolve the injection hole by using prepared statements.

```
$query = 'select * from resources where ';
if(!empty($_POST['formats'])){ 
foreach($_POST['formats'] as $key => $format) {
    $query .= 'stage LIKE :stage' . $key . ' or ';
    $execute[':stage' . $key] = '%' . trim($format) . '%';
}
}
if(!empty($_POST['topics'])){
foreach($_POST['topics'] as $key => $topic) {
    $query .= 'topic LIKE :topic' . $key . ' or ';
    $execute[':topic' . $key] = '%' . trim($topic)  . '%';
}
}
$query = rtrim($query, ' or ');
if(!empty($execute)) {
    echo $query;
    print_r($execute);
    //$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    //$stmt->execute($execute);
} else {
    echo 'You must search for something';
}
```

Gives you a query of

> select * from resources where stage LIKE :stage0 or stage LIKE :stage1 or topic LIKE :topic0 or topic LIKE :topic1 or topic LIKE :topic2 or topic LIKE :topic3

and bound values of:

```
Array
(
    [:stage0] => %test%
    [:stage1] => %test1%
    [:topic0] => %value1%
    [:topic1] => %value2%
    [:topic2] => %value3%
    [:topic3] => %value4%
)
```

Here's the initial code I had for when I thought the data was paired..

```
foreach($formats as $key => $format) {
    $topic = $topics[$key];
    $query .= '(stage LIKE :stage' . $key . ' and topic LIKE :topic' . $key . ') or ';
    $execute[':stage' . $key] = '%' . trim($format) . '%';
    $execute[':topic' . $key] = '%' . trim($topic)  . '%';
}
```

A few links on prepared statements:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: thanks. not too familiar with prepared statement. why     //$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    //$stmt->execute($execute); commented out

Comment: Oo you can uncomment that, that was just for an example of how to use it. I don't have a DB set up so can't execute.

Comment: should i comment out    echo $query;
    print_r($execute);

Comment: thanks. just one minor request. because i wasn't really familiar with prepared statement i ommited included the following code, i have added under my initial post. would any change have to be made to them?

Comment: Doesn't that SQL query search for all ORs in parallel? Shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM resources WHERE (stage LIKE :stage0 OR stage LIKE :stage1) AND (topic LIKE :topic0 OR topic LIKE :topic1)` etc.

Comment: Yes this is looking for any of the provided values. I had something written up earlier for if they were paired but I thought you'd said the data wasn't paired..

Comment: Updated with some links and previous code for if they were to be paired.

Comment: thanks, i unfortunatetly receive the following error explode() expects parameter to be string array given

Comment: There's no explode in my code...Are you sure you ran my code and it worked for you?

Comment: sorry for all those questions, but the size of the array for format or topic is undertermined in advance

Comment: Okay, first please unaccept my answer. You should accept an answer when it works. Going forward what array are you referring to, isn't `$_POST['formats']` a string? If not then how did `$formats = explode(',', $formatsArray);` work?

Comment: $_POST['formats'] returns an array such as ["blogs", "video", "books", "podcasts"], etc

Comment: So when you said an hour ago `thanks i have added an update at the bottom of my initial post. how would i proceed with the next step` did you just type the code in and not run it?

Comment: it was my fault. i proceeded by assumption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88331/discussion-between-chris85-and-user3907211).

Comment: hey thanks for your response. i receive another error here: fatal error call to member function execute() on boolean in line 45            $stmt->execute($execute);

Comment: What does the output give you if you revert from executing to the query values?

Comment: thanks for sticking through,.i notice the problem it has to do with the expectation of the query in the sense that i had for instance in the array videos, when the query was expecting video, so i remove the s the error went away, and similar case for other items in the array

Comment: So this is all set now or you need a way to depluralize the phrases?