# Designing a filter for query?

Tags: php, pdo

So, I want to create a filter to pick choices from. I have created 12 drop-down menu for users to select values from, and then click a button. Lets say these are the drop downs  A,B,..L each with their own value.

Now using php i want to query a table in sql server where those 12 values apply.

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=address,port;Database=dbname',$username, $password); 
$sth = $conn->prepare("Select COL1 FROM myTable WHERE A LIKE ? AND B LIKE ? AND C LIKE ? ... L LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(array($valA,$valB,...$valL);
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
```

Is this even the right way or the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you want exact matches or partial matches? Are you going to have a result if all 12 fields are set, maybe you should build query dynamically?

Comment: @chris85 I am going to go with partial matches; hence the LIKE. But i have default values on all of them set to '%', because not all of them have to be set. Does that help? How do i go about it doing it dynamicallY?

Comment: Loop through the POST/GET array and append the query column and placeholder to the query. Append the values in a separate array as well. Here's a answer I've given previously which did it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302633/convert-an-array-into-individual-strings/32302897#32302897, maybe that will be more useful for you than it was to OP. That's using `mysqli` but shouldn't be much work to convert.

Comment: Well i already have those values. $valA has the value of A dropdown. $valB has value of B dropdown and so on. I have already got that part working. My question is when i am querying it to sql server, is that right?

Comment: That should be correct, did you try it and get an error? Is the question more `is this the correct usage of prepared statements`?

Comment: Is this a database schema question, or are you just looking for a way to work with a schema you already have? If you are making the database layout alongside this plugin, I'd suggest having a tags table for your filters, and that table maps out each tag specifically to the things being filtered, then do something like join the tables and do a SELECT * WHERE tag IN (your, list, of, tags)